# Visual Studio Code uninstallation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to uninstall vs code completely so that none of my past modified settings should stay. I even deleted `.vscode` file from `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.vscode` .
But when I again installed vs code, all my previous work and settings were already present, so there was affect even after completely uninstalling it. Can someone please help me through it??

Comment: I wouldn't want the uninstall to remove all my work - for example, if I was uninstalling it so I could install a newer version. What is the *actual* problem - perhaps you're just looking for a way to reset some settings to the default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my PC (system-wide install) the directory you mention only contains extensions. User data is stored at:

```
%APPDATA%\Code
```

You can always find your settings directory from *File/ Preferences/ Setttings*. Click on the *More actions* (`…`) link beside the *User Settings* tab and select "Open settings.json". You can then *Copy Path*, *Reveal in Explorer* or see the path in breadcrumbs.